# Create multiple borders using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to recreate the following in html5. I know how to create rectangles, but I'm not sure how to have them  have a hole in the middle.

[image: The design I'm looking for]

Comment: Assuming from tags it should be drawn on canvas. Have you tried anything already?

Comment: context.clearRect worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You build it with lines and rectangles using the well documented html5 canvas context api.

context.fillStyle, context.strokeStyle, context.fillRect, context.strokeRect, context.beginPath, context.moveTo, context.lineTo

http://jsfiddle.net/DG7km/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.lineWidth = 2;
//
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(100, 0);
ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
ctx.lineTo(0, 100);
ctx.stroke();
//
ctx.strokeStyle = "#aaa";
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(90, 10);
ctx.lineTo(10, 10);
ctx.lineTo(10, 90);
ctx.moveTo(85, 15);
ctx.lineTo(15, 15);
ctx.lineTo(15, 85);
ctx.stroke();
//
ctx.strokeStyle = "#777";
ctx.fillStyle = "#aaa";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 60, 60);
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(80, 20);
ctx.lineTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(20, 80);
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create it in pure CSS/HTML (no canvas), you can do it with box shadows and borders like so

```
.container {
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    border-right:3px solid black;
    border-bottom:3px solid black;
    padding:35px;
}
.content {
    border-top:2px solid grey;
    border-left:2px solid grey;
    height:250px;
    width:200px;
    box-shadow:
       10px  10px 0 15px white,
       5px  5px 0 15px hsl(0, 0%, 80%),
       12px  12px 0 25px white,
       7px  7px 0 25px hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
}
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/97AYz/1/)